# Mapbox not showing in Vite-created React.js application

Tags: reactjs, npm, mapbox-gl-js

I am building a React JS application (templated using Vite) and need to create a map with a list of markers. Using Mapbox, I have installed using `npm install --save react-map-gl mapbox-gl` and have the following code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactMapGL from "react-map-gl";

export default function OurCampusesMap() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: -33.865143,
    longitude: 151.2099,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 10,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMapGL {...viewport}></ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, nothing shows up in the preview (not even an error message telling me to put in my Mapbox token.

When I check the console, I get the following errors:

**Error 1**

```
GET https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v%3CYOUR_MAPBOX_VERSION%3E/mapbox-gl.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**Error 2**

```
suppress-nextjs-warning.ts:6 Error: Could not resolve "mapbox-gl" imported by "react-map-gl". Is it installed?
    at optional-peer-dep:__vite-optional-peer-dep:mapbox-gl:react-map-gl:1:7
```

I've tried uninstalling `react-map-gl` and reinstalling using npm. I was expecting this error to disappear, and the Mapbox map to appear.